# Laravel carbon failed to parse time string

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I need to select users with specific age from model User, but have this error:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (birth) at position 0 (b): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

part of controller:

```
$users = User::where(Carbon::parse('birth')->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y'), '>=', 18)->get();
```

when i use it in view all working fine:

```
 @foreach ($userss as $user)

 <?php  $age_year = Carbon::parse($user->birth)->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y'); ?>


@endforeach
```

Thanks for answers!

Comment: I think datetime format issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller example, you are trying to parse the string *'birth'* instead of the database field 'birth'.

Since you are returning a collection, just run through the returned collections with the filter() method before sending it down to your view. You can also use the **age** property instead of doing a diff

```
$users = User::get()->filter(function($user, $key) {
    return (Carbon::parse($user->birth)->age >= 18);
});
```

I did not test this, so you may get some typos, but this is how you will want to accomplish this task.

Comment: thanks, that's is it. Function is missed: $users = $users_all->filter(function ($patients, $key) {
return (Carbon::parse($user->birth)->age >= 18);
});

Comment: Thanks. I added the function declaration

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
User::where('birth','>=', Carbon::now()->subYears(18)->toDateTimeString());
```

not tested yet, but hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carbon`'s `diff` helper to calculate age, and `filter` method to filter objects(`User` in this case).

```
$users = User::get()->filter($user, $key) {
    return Carbon\Carbon::now()->diff($user->birth)->y >= 18;
});
```

There are also other helpers functions available with `Carbon`, some are:

```
// diffInYears(), diffInMonths(), diffInWeeks()
// diffInDays(), diffInWeekdays(), diffInWeekendDays()
// diffInHours(), diffInMinutes(), diffInSeconds()
```

Please review this for more information:
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/