# How to calculate age using carbon in array map function?

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon, array-map

This application built in Lavavel 5. I had a table with year of birth value. I query the table using this query:

```
  $tarikh = DB::table('itemregistrations')
            ->select('itemregistrations.lahir_dd', 'itemregistrations.lahir_mm', 'itemregistrations.lahir_yy')
            ->get();
```

dd($tarikh); produce this output:

```
Collection {#709 ▼
#items: array:1123 [▼
0 => {#681 ▼
  +"lahir_dd": 9
  +"lahir_mm": "June"
  +"lahir_yy": 1979
}
1 => {#670 ▶}
2 => {#680 ▶}
3 => {#713 ▶}
```

I want to calculate the age using carbon and insert into the collection using array map(my earlier code):

```
 $tarikh->map(function ($detail) {$detail->Umur = "{$detail->lahir_yy}->diffInYears(\Carbon::now())";
        return $detail;
    });
```

Changed to Ijas suggested code:

```
  $tarikh->map(function ($detail) {
     $detail->Umur = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($detail->lahir_yy)->diffInYears();
     return $detail;
 });
```

Comment: whats `->lahir_yy` ?

Comment: birth year value...in integer type

Comment: is this related issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649128/laravel-carbon-failed-to-parse-time-string

Comment: I don't think so. You are passing the field, not the field name. It's the right way. When you `dd($detail->lahir_yy)` what do you get ? the year right ?

Comment: it shows 1979...

 $tarikh->map(function ($detail) {
            // $detail->Umur = "{$detail->t_lahir}"->diff(\Carbon::now()->year);
            $detail->Umur = Carbon::parse("{$detail->lahir_yy}")->diffInYears();
            dd($detail->lahir_yy);
            return $detail;
        });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate diff as,

```
$tarikh->map(function ($detail) {
    $detail->Umur = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($detail->lahir_yy)->diffInYears();
    return $detail;
});
```

> Updated : Re-generated your results and applied the given solution.

Fiddle : https://implode.io/i1GanD

For the given context, This works as you expected.

The error erased by modifying some code with this:

```
  $tarikh->map(function ($detail) {

        $detail->Umur = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y',$detail->lahir_yy)->diffInYears(); 

        return $detail;
    });
```

Comment: why it produce error DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (0) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character..is there any changes need to be made?

Comment: the birth year in integer..need to change the type?

Comment: No. You can check the fiddle. Integer is fine.

Comment: I had made changes on the question...is it because of the array arrangement?

Comment: Updated the answer. It works for the given context. May be toy have malformed data ? not sure.

Comment: same error still appear...DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (0) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character

Comment: it is highlighting this code in the error ..   parent::__construct($time, $timezone);
        if (isset($locale)) {
            setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, $locale);

Comment: Don't you think this is out of context ? You can ask a separate question.

Comment: okay..thank you...i will expand this question in separate question..i will accept your answer as it is proved in the fiddle..thanks for your contribution and time Ijas

Comment: Hi Ijas...I had modified the code by using \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y',$detail->lahir_yy) erase the error..thank you for your help..i updated your fiddle with revised code.